# AngularJS - ng-view Not Loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application I am trying to set up as a SPA with AngularJS that hooks into a REST API off of our internal SharePoint site. I am having issues with `ng-view` and getting any of the views to actually load. Both views are setup as `ng-template` and whenever it tries to find one, it kicks back a 404 Not Found like it's still looking for a separate page.

**[Here is the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cKAtiHjBVQc2Wdy8lLlU?p=preview)**.

I know that none of the data will load because of this coming from an internal SharePoint list, but the views should at least load something to give us an idea of what is going on.

Edit: I cannot actually answer this since my account is too new, but I needed to move the `ng-template` script blocks inside of the `ng-app` div so that they would be recognized.

Comment: You should also load jQuery before Angular so Angular can use it. But why even load jQuery? Why not use Angular's $http service like you did in one spot?

Comment: Indeed you found the correct answer a directive won't be processed if it isn't in the context of the ng-app that has those directives defined (either directly or within module dependencies)

Comment: @EddieMongeJr - I didn't even notice that it's a bit of both $http and jQuery. Oi, apparently I need either more or less coffee. I'm going to just switch them all over to $http. jQuery is included in our SharePoint site so I had been using that for the ajax calls since I don't have a great deal of experience with Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that this doesn't stay as unanswered:

I needed to move the `ng-template` script blocks inside of the `ng-app` div so that they would be recognized by Angular and not loaded in the wrong order compared to the DOM.